# Notifications not triggering

Tags: bug, android-app

Everything regarding stack notifications is set to enable on my phone, but I haven't been receiving any of them since I'm running an Android. On iPhone, it did work.

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: samsung
- Device Model: SM-G930F
- OS Version: 6.0.1 (G930FUBU1BQB1)

Comment: _since I'm running an Android. On iPhone, it did work_ I am getting notifications properly without any problem on my Android 5.1 /CM 12.1. Consider adding root status too. I think it may help the devs. Because in root, you may did some mistake in notif config.

Comment: I added a question for another issue. But in the image in the question, you can find the SE app icon in the notif bar beside whatsapp.  FYI https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292896/own-profile-last-seen-show-incorrect-info

Comment: Are notifications show for other apps?

Comment: Make sure you are logged in, to at least one site. Also, when opening the app do you see Feeds? Can you open the achievements dialog and see them?

Comment: In my experience, the mobile site is better as the app (for example, here you can also review). I use it from an android firefox now.

Comment: The app works properly, i do get to see all my stuff, and this is not rooted